What is the purpose of this metal piece on my closet door and is it OK to remove it?
I have a wide closet with two segmented doors and there's a mating pair of these things screwed onto the edges.

(Mating pair as in the other one has the part that sticks out on the bottom instead of the top.)
Whatever purpose they're meant to serve isn't obvious to me and I have no idea what terms to search for to even begin to figure it out.
Regardless, I've banged my leg on them on more than one occasion when I only open one of the doors and it's very painful.
What are these supposed to do and is it safe to remove them?

It is a bifold door surface aligner.  A pair of them keeps the bottom leading edges of the doors aligned in the front to back direction.  At the top the track does this job.   It is safe to remove them.   The doors may be naturally aligned or they may (now or later or seasonally) show a gap.  It's not unsafe, just ugly.

Thanks. Now that I have a name and a purpose, I have options. If I want to keep it aligned, I can look into alternatives designs, or experiment with buying a replacement and then cutting it down to project less.
